# why only $\sup(S) $ can satisfy $M - \epsilon <= x$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

in real analysis, for an elment to be the superior of the set it have to be:

1. bigger than all other elements  (for every element $x$ in set, $x \le M$)
2. for any positive epsilon $\epsilon > 0$, there exist an elment of the set that is bigger than M, $M - \epsilon \le x$

the first condition of being an upper bound is totally understandable, but the second one, i mean any upper bound can satisfy it, the all the upper bounds are $\sup(S) $

Comment: The second condition states that $M-\epsilon$ is NOT an upper bound for all $\epsilon\gt0$ i.e. the supremum is the minimum upper bound.

Comment: I know that, the sup is the lowest bound along the upper bounds, but this condition do not help it, since any upper bound can achieve it, and worse, even some elements  (in some sets of course) can achieve it

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. No other upper bound should have the property of being the minimum upper bound.

Comment: yeah, i figured it out, other upper bounds will require, $\epsilon $ to be greater than a number n, thanks.

Comment: Use `\le` $\le$ and `\ge` $\ge$ please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often the definition of the least upper bound is given as follows. Let $S$ be a set bounded above. We say $\sup S$ is the least upper bound of $S$ if:

1. $\sup S$ is an upper bound for $S$;
2. If $\ell$ is an upper bound for $S$, then $\ell\geq\sup S$.

From this, we can prove that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $s\in S$ such that $\sup S-\varepsilon<s$. Suppose there exists some $\varepsilon>0$ such that for all $s\in S$, $\sup S-\varepsilon\geq s$. Then $\sup S-\varepsilon$ must also be an upper bound for $S$, since $s$ is an arbitrary element of $S$. But this implies that $\sup S$ is not the least upper bound of $S$, since $\sup S-\varepsilon<\sup S$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, which is a contradiction.

Now try to prove that if $\ell$ is an upper bound for $S$ such that for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $s\in S$ such that $\ell-\varepsilon<s$, then $\ell=\sup s$, and you'll see that only $\sup S$ can satisfy the property given above.